# flask + uwsgi: No handlers could be found for logger

Tags: python, logging, flask, uwsgi

I am running a python flask app using uwsgi and nginx. I am having trouble getting the app modules to log. If i run the flask app by itself, i can see the logs properly formatted, but in uwsgi, i see 'no handlers could be found for logger...' and the logs are missing. prints show up fine. Could someone help with what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

I run uwsgi as

`/usr/local/bin/uwsgi --ini /root/uwsgi.ini`

```
# cat /root/uwsgi.ini
[uwsgi]
base=/root/mainapp
app = mainapp
module = %(app)
pythonpath = %(base)
socket = /tmp/mainapp.sock
chmod-socket = 666
callable = app
logto = /var/log/mainapp/app.log
paste-logger = %p


[formatters]
keys: detailed

[handlers]
keys: console

[loggers]
keys: root, module1, module2, module3

[formatter_detailed]
format: %(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s %(module)s:%(lineno)d:  %(message)s

[handler_console]
class: StreamHandler
args: []
formatter: detailed

[logger_root]
level: DEBUG
handlers: 

[logger_module1]
level: DEBUG
qualname: module1
handlers: console

[logger_module2]
level: DEBUG
qualname: module2
handlers: console

[logger_module3]
level: DEBUG
qualname: module3
handlers: console
```

and in the module, i call

```
import logging
log = logging.getLogger('module1')
log.info('hello world')
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured Flask to use the logger? Off the top of my head something like this should work

```
app.config['LOG_FILE'] = 'application.log'

# Configure logger.
if not app.debug:
    import logging
    from logging import FileHandler
    file_handler = FileHandler(app.config['LOG_FILE'])
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

Comment: i do have the same logging config in logging.conf and in the flask app say
     import logging.config
     logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')

Answer (score 0):

looks like i have to instantiate flask's app.logger before i can do anything...this did the trick...set addhandler on app.logger and

```
import logging
import logging.config
shandler = logging.StreamHandler()
shandler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
app.logger.addHandler(shandler)
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
```